# EF Stored Procedure affects multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I started working with EF and have what I hope is a simple example and question.  I have a stored procedure which accepts a username and password, validates them and, if ok, updates a session table with the userid and returns a session number. Procedure works no problem.  So I was just experimenting with EF to the same thing but not sure how. Model has 2 tables: Users (UserName, Password, ID) and Sessions (SessionKey, UserID, datetime).  I imported the sproc but not sure where to go from there.  So, should something like this be done using EF or is better just to do it the old way?  Thanks

Comment: There's really no reason to use both EF ***and*** a stored procedure.  If you're going to just call a stored procedure, skip the EF overhead and use dapper to make your serialization/deserialization a bit more reasonable.

Comment: That's really my question - is their any advantage to using EF to do this?  I was hoping this would be a good example to get my feet wet but it appears much more complicated that I thought it would be.  - Also still curious how to do it

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't have rich stored procedure support because its an ORM, not a SQL replacement. Have a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/31784986/2946329

Comment: The true power of EF lies in the ability to map data seamlessly, not invoke stored procedures.  You certainly could, but it would be complete overkill.  Either move the stored procedure logic into C# code or invoke the stored procedure with Dapper or ADO.NET, although personally I'd take Dapper every single time :).

Comment: Thanks, been using ADO but will take a look at Dapper .. more to learn.

Comment: dapper is pretty slick -thanks for the heads up